# Symfony3.4 : Postgis, Error in doctrine Schema

Tags: postgresql, postgis, symfony-3.4

I am runing an application using Postgresql and Postgis, it was working fine since i was using postgresql-9.6 and postgis-2.3 but after i upgraded to postgresql-10 and postgis-2.4 i got an error while trying to create the schema using the doctrine command:

In AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 76:

```
    SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "min_value" does not exist    
    LINE 1: SELECT min_value, increment_by FROM "meas_id_seq"
```

In PDOConnection.php line 106:

```
    SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "min_value" does not exist    
    LINE 1: SELECT min_value, increment_by FROM "meas_id_seq"
```

In PDOConnection.php line 104:

```
    SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "min_value" does not exist  
    LINE 1: SELECT min_value, increment_by FROM "meas_id_seq"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Symfony bundle https://github.com/jsor/doctrine-postgis.
Wich is not compatible with the latest versions of PostGIS.